# register hive udf using hue api

Tags: api, hadoop, user-defined-functions, hive, hue

How to register a UDF by using HUE API?
I am using below code but it's unable to register it.

```
Query query1=new Query("create temporary function calculate as 'com.sample.MYUDF'",configuration,hadoop_user);
thriftclient.query(query1);
Query query2=new Query("select calculate('2/23/2010') from dummy",configuration,hadoop_user);
thriftclient.query(query2);
```

Executing this code throws INVALID FUNCTION calculate on last line.

Comment: Resolved - Have to do in following way

Comment: List<String> configuration=new ArrayList<String>();
  String addJar = "ADD JAR /home/hadoop/ankit/udf/udf.jar";
  configuration.add(addJar);
  String cmd = "CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION check AS 'com.infosys.newPoc.DateUDF'";
  configuration.add(cmd); and pass this with query

Answer (score 1):

Check the **Query Editor** .. Click on the **Advanced** tab
On the left you will find what you require